# What is the use of event.preventDefault(); with respect to events in lightning web components. does it refer to prevent bubble phase execution

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-dom

I understand that it stops the default phase of execution of the events, but what does it exactly mean.

```
//child component.js
import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
    handleChange(event)
    {   
        event.preventDefault();
        const name = event.target.value;
        const selectEvent = new CustomEvent('mycustomevent',{
            detail: name
        }
        );
        this.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
    }
}

//parent component.js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
export default class ChildToParentCommLwc extends LightningElement {
    @track msg;
    handleCustomEvent(event){
        const textval = event.detail;
        this.msg = textval.toUpperCase();
        console.log('event handled in child to parent comm lwc');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. From the javascript code it looks like you're trying to read something from input field and passing it to parent. `event.preventDefault()` is definitely not needed if it's input field. Let me know if it's something else I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand when we need to use event.preventDefault(). Does this stop the default phase(bubble phase) of execution of the event, and how does the event execute after it.

Comment: As I understand you can use it if u want to execute some custom logic rather than continuing default behaviour. Like submit refreshes the page so u can use there. Or use for file upload too. This topic is pretty vast.

Comment: Also after spring 2020 changes primitive datatypes doesn't require track(it's reactive by default). You can use it for objects or arrays

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for the info :)